# problem with Distinct query in subsonic 3

Tags: c#, subsonic

```
ProductCollection select = new 
        Select(Product.SupplierIDColumn).From<Product>().Distinct()
        .ExecuteAsCollection<ProductCollection>();
```

http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Distinct

From above example I am trying to get distinct category from my table but many problems comes

1. I can not put column like this `Product.SupplierIDColumn` I dont know why my class `EventListing` has no intellisense for these columns
2. `Distinct()` function is not available after `From<EventListing>()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, it looks like the SqlQuery class in SubSonic 2 had a Distinct() method, but the SqlQuery class in SubSonic 3 does not. You could try SS2 instead of 3, or if you are using 3, I suggest using Linq expressions instead. In other words, something like:

```
var data = (from x in db.Products
            select x.SupplierId)
           .Distinct();
```

-or-

```
var data = db.Products.Select(x => x.SupplierId).Distinct();
```